# In my Blazor server app, I want to read out the username of the client, but I see always my username with that I was logged to the server. Why?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication, httpcontext

In my Blazor server app, I want to read out the username of the clients and show it on the screen like "Hello userxxx".But whoever opens the page it is always shown the username with that I was logged on to the server where the Blazor app runs. For testing, whether the update on screen could be faulty, I write the read username also directly to a file. But also there I always read the same username.

I am using Windows Authentication. I have recently just updated my project from net core 3.1 to .Net6. Nothing changed else. Could that be the problem?

Additionally: before the update The user was asked always for username and password (Windows Auth) But currently this is not asked anymore.

I am using following code in my razor cs page for reading out the clients username:

Update-1: I noticed that in the web.config the definition for the windows auth. has dissapeared. I tried to add it again, but get Error when web page opened. 0x80070021. This configuration section cannot be used at this path...

```
 public void read_user_name()
    { 
            
            TagService.LoginUserName = (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Remove(0, 5); // deleting the domain part;
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(log_path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Logged in user : " + TagService.LoginUserName + " " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
    }
```